# How to create an index pattern in Opensearch using API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, shell, aws-elasticsearch, opensearch

I want to create an index pattern using Opensearch API. I tried to replicate what could be made graphically in the following image window, using as *index pattern name* cwl-* and then as *time field* @timestamp.
My domain has OpenSearch 1.2 installed.

[image]

Using curl (directly modifiend the command in [kibana doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/master/index-patterns-api-create.html)):

```
curl -u '****:*****' -X POST "https://******.eu-central-1.es.amazonaws.com/api/index_patterns/index_pattern" -H 'osd-xsrf: true' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "index_pattern": {
     "title": "cwl-*",
     "timeFieldName": "@timestamp"
  }
}'
```

but I receive

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Rejecting mapping update to [api] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [_doc, index_patterns]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Rejecting mapping update to [api] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [_doc, index_patterns]"},"status":400}
```

Comment: Are you using any sort of IAM authentication?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary just the Fine-grained access control but it works because I don't have any problem in performing other requests...

Comment: Ahhhhhh - remove `saved_objects` from your URL.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Unfortunately I had already tried, it says `{"statusCode":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"Not Found"}`

Comment: Your URL is somehow wrong - I don't have docs in front of me right now but try removing `_dashboards` from the URL and if that doesn't work, also remove `api`

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I tried to perform a login through curl storing a cookie, it seems to avoid the authentication failure but then I can't create the index pattern anyway (this could depend on the url provided).

Comment: Yes as your payload is wrong - read example provided here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/master/index-patterns-api-create.html (hint: you need a `index_pattern` object) etc.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Nothing. I've updated the question so it could be easier to be understand and reproduced with curl instead of python

Comment: Your question now seems to not be related to OpenSearch or AWS itself but more regarding Elasticsearch - I would add the regular `elasticsearch` tag to get views from Elasticsearch experts :) one step closer!

Answer (score 1):

```
curl -u '****:*****' -X POST "https://******.eu-central-1.es.amazonaws.com/api/index_patterns/cwl-*" -H 'osd-xsrf: true' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "index_pattern": {
     "title": "cwl-*",
     "timeFieldName": "@timestamp"
  }
}'
```

change `api/index_patterns/index_pattern` to `api/index_patterns/cwl-*` and try again?

Comment: It works in a sense that the command creates something but I cannot see anything among saved objects and seams that in this way only an index which name is "api" is created not an index pattern therefore each time I access the dashboard, once it finds data, it ask me if I want to create it.

Comment: if you want the index-pattern to be global, try to add this attribute in header: securitytenant: "global"?

Comment: already done, I've added -H 'securitytenant: global' to the curl string

Comment: @Dresult Did you ever manage to figure this out? I am encountering the same issue, it seems.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me in OpenSearch 1.3 when I added an ID in the URI and used `saved_objects` instead of `index_patterns`.

So your cURL-request should work when looking like this.

```
curl -u '****:*****' -X POST "https://<opensearch-dashboards-host>.eu-central-1.es.amazonaws.com/api/saved_objects/index-pattern/<ID>" 
-H 'osd-xsrf: true' 
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' 
-d 
   '{
      "index_pattern": {
         "title": "cwl-*",
         "timeFieldName": "@timestamp"
      }
    }'
```

Comment: I am getting `no handler found for uri [/api/saved_objects/index-pattern/cwl-*] and method [POST]` error for this.. using opensearch1.3.

Comment: @K.Thanvi This is probably because you are sending the request to the OpenSearch-host. The request is meant to be sent to the OpenSearch Dashboards-host (or Kibana-host if you use that). Using the Dev Tools will send the request to the OpenSearch-host.

Comment: Thanks! Yes that was the issue. i had to send the request to my `<opensearch_domain>/_dashboards/api/saved_objects/index-pattern` endpoint.